# Person ID # with two records from a many-to-many relationship Access 2007

Tags: sql, ms-access

[image: http://imgur.com/uzPGs]

Above is a screen cap of my schema.

The visits table has a list of personal ID numbers and ICD is a list of codes that pertain to a certain person.  You can see from the junction table that there's a many-to-many relationship between Visits and ICDTable.  I'm trying to make a query that allows a person to type in two records in ICDTable and only return the Visit ID # if a person has both of them.  I tried to amend this from a previous query I wrote but I can't figure out what's going on.  The query doesn't 'fail' per se in that it allows me to search for some things, but it's obviously wrong.  What am I missing? Gracias.

```
SELECT Visits.ID, Inf.desc, Sore.desc
FROM tblKentuckyCounties 
INNER JOIN 
(
    ICDTable AS Inf 
    INNER JOIN 
    (
        (
            (
                Visits 
                INNER JOIN ICDTable AS InfVisits 
                    ON Visits.ID=InfVisits.VisitsID
            ) 
            INNER JOIN ICDTable AS SoreVisits 
                ON Visits.ID=SoreVisits.ID
        ) 
        INNER JOIN ICDTable AS Sore 
            ON SoreVisits.ICD_IDFK=Sore.ID
    ) ON Inf.ID=Visits.ICD_IDFK
) 
    ON tblKentuckyCounties.ID=Visits.County
WHERE Inf.desc=[enter first term] 
    AND Sore.desc=[enter second term]
```

thanks for edit.

Ok, so I found out what I needed to do. Below this text is the working query for anyone interested in how to do this sort of thing

```
SELECT DISTINCT Visits.KHA_ID, Visits.totalCharges
FROM (Visits INNER JOIN (ICDTable INNER JOIN ICDVisitsJxn ON ICDTable.ICD9ID = ICDVisitsJxn.ICD_IDFK) ON Visits.ID = ICDVisitsJxn.VisitsIDFK) INNER JOIN (ICDTable AS ICDTable_1 INNER JOIN ICDVisitsJxn AS ICDVisitsJxn_1 ON ICDTable_1.ICD9ID = ICDVisitsJxn_1.ICD_IDFK) ON Visits.ID = ICDVisitsJxn_1.VisitsIDFK
WHERE (((ICDTable.Description) Like [enter term]) AND ((ICDTable_1.Description) Like [enter another term]));
```

Comment: the aliases were chosen for clarity with the last query.  they could really be called anything.

Comment: correction, i suppose it does fail. it doesn't do close to what i want it to.  but it at least lets me run a faulty query, i guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could divide your query into a subquery containing only ICDVisits and ICDtable (1). In a new query you then join Visits with this subquery twice (2).

(1)

```
SELECT ICDTable.Description, ICDVisits.VisitsIDFK
FROM ICDTable INNER JOIN ICDVisits ON ICDTable.ICD9ID = ICDVisits.ICD_IDFK;
```

(2)

```
SELECT Visits.ID
FROM query1 INNER JOIN (query2 INNER JOIN Visits ON query2.VisitsIDFK = Visits.ID) ON
query1.VisitsIDFK = Visits.ID
WHERE (((query1.Description) Like 'a') AND ((query2.Description) Like 'b'));
```

(Query 1 & 2 being the join of ICDVisits and ICDTable).

Forgot to mention it: You don't have to use the ID field inside ICDVisitsJxn as a primary key, you could just make the fields VisitsIDFK and ICD_IDFK the primary key. This would avoid duplicated entries.

Query 1 & 2 (being the same obviously):
[image: Query1 & 2]

Combined Query:

[image: Combined Query]

Comment: the first query runs and returns the ICD.Description and the Visit ID #.  the second query returns no results, however.

Comment: This work for me (given your schema), if the correct data exists in the tables. I corrected the naming to make it easier understandable, maybe I entered a typo. This is now the exact statement that works for me. I'll try and upload a picture of the query, maybe that helps.

Comment: please, if you don't mind.  let me try these again and see what's up.

Comment: Just for clarification: You need to edit the part "(query1.Description) Like 'a'" and  "(query2.Description) Like 'b'" accordingly to your data, I don't know if that was clear. In my ICD table there is one description called 'a' and one description called 'b'.

Comment: thanks for the help, i didn't end up doing exactly what you did to solve it, but i got it working and yours was the impetus for innovation.